# Java conditional statement issues

Tags: java

I just started Java yesterday and been having some issues with conditional statements.
Trying to disable and autoclicker when my mouse is up, and enable it when my mouse is down. But the clicker still clicks? How should I have this set up?

```
public class Random {
public boolean held;
Random(){
    held = false;
}
public void printhi() {
    System.out.print("hi");
}


public void setHeld(boolean held) throws AWTException {
    this.held = held;
    if(held == true) {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        if(held != true) {
            
        }
    }

    
    
        
}
```

Comment: what the second if condition `if(held != true` mean?

Comment: `if (held)` will suffice, you don't need the `== true` bit. Either way, whatever you put after `if(held != true) {` will be unreachable code and never run, since at that point `held` can only ever be `true`.

Comment: You shouldn't name your class `Random`, because there is already a class `java.util.Random`, which might result in a naming conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Just take another look at your logic:

```
if(held == true) {
    if(held != true) {
        
    }
}
```

I only removed some lines to hint you to the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Random {
    public boolean held = false;

    Random() {
    }

    public static void printhi() {
        System.out.print("hi");
    }


    public void setHeld(boolean held) throws AWTException {
        this.held = held;
        if (held) {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        } else {
            //do stuff
        }


    }
}
```